# Grep command for including a set of letter and excluding the others

Tags: grep

I need all files with lines including the word "confidential" But not having this sentence "waste paper is confidential and need to be disposed"

```
grep confidential 100*.cvt
```

gives me lines that contain word "confidential"

How do I remove programs with this sentence "waste paper is confidential and need to be disposed"

```
grep confidential 100*.cvt | grep -v waste paper is confidential and need to be disposed 100*.cvt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -l` to get just the filenames from the first `grep`. Then use that as the filename arguments to the second grep.

You also need to quote the pattern if it contains whitespace.

```
grep -l confidential 100*.cvt | xargs grep -l -v 'waste paper is confidential and need to be disposed'
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't show me the line where this is found with the name of the file. What option should I be using?

Comment: The problem is that the first grep just returns the filenames so they can be filtered out by the second grep. Use the solution in the other answer to get what you want, since it reverses the order.

Answer (score 0):

first grep list all the files excluding the ones with required sentence

second grep shows matching files by also showing the matched string

```
grep -L "waste paper is confidential and need to be disposed" ./100*.cvt | xargs grep -E "confidential"
```